# Show a set number of <li>s and then hide them to reveal another set number of <li>s

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a carousel, using floated list items.

When *Next* is pressed the current 4 visible `li`s are hidden and the next 4 shown for as many times as needed. Though, there may not always be another 4 to show, as in the case below there would only be 2 more to display.

When *Prev* is pressed the current 4 visible `li`s are hidden and the previous 4 shown.

It doesn't need to loop i.e. if *Next* is pressed enough times it will reach the end, it wont just start back from the beginning again.

http://jsfiddle.net/tw16/5NB6G/

**HTML:**

```
<div id="left">Prev</div>
<ul>
    <li>Test 1</li>
    <li>Test 2</li>
    <li>Test 3</li>
    <li>Test 4</li>
    <li>Test 5</li>
    <li>Test 6</li>
</ul>
<div id="right">Next</div>
```

**jQuery/JavaScript:**

```
var listLength = $('ul li').length;
var listCounter = 0;

$("#right").click(function() {
    if (listCounter == listLength - 1) {
        $("ul li").show(400);
        listCounter = 0;
    }
    else {
        $('ul li').eq(listCounter).hide(400);
        listCounter++;
    }
});
```

Unfortunately, I haven't been able to adapt the code to the requirements above.

Comment: Can you clarify? You keep talking about "current 4" but I see 6 <li>

Comment: @Over he want's pagination with 4 `<li>`s at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I experimented a bit and came up with the following:

```
var total = $('ul li').length;
var start = 0;
var count = 4;

update = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < total; i++) {
        el = $("ul li").eq(i);
        if (i >= start && i < start + count)
            el.show(400);
        else
            el.hide(400);
    }
}

$("#right").click(function() {
    start += count;
    if (start >= total)
        start = 0;
    update();
});

$("#left").click(function() {
    start -= count;
    if (start < 0)
        start = Math.floor(total / count) * count;
    update();
});
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/5NB6G/43/ for a live demo.

**EDIT:** I just noticed that you don't need wrapping over the end/beginning. You can use the following then in conjunction with the `update` function defined above:

```
$("#right").click(function() {
    start += count;
    if (start >= total)
        start -= count;
    update();
});

$("#left").click(function() {
    start -= count;
    start = start < 0 ? 0 : start;
    update();
});
```

Comment: Great solution. This is just what I needed. No need to add extra markup or change the styling I already have. I have modified the *animation* slightly from my original. I will probably experiment some more with it, maybe change from sliding to fading etc. http://jsfiddle.net/tw16/5NB6G/44/. Next task is looking through the code to try and decipher how it works.

Comment: The global variables `start` and `count` hold information about the range to be shown (with `start` obviously being the index of the first item to show and `count` being the number of items to show). When the user clicks one of the buttons, the `start` value is adapted to the new index of the first `li` to show. The `update` function simply shows all needed items while hiding all the others. Have fun.

Comment: Why would you make your own carousel when there is a very stable,  mature version of the same thing with more features already out there?  I don't see any advantage to this approach?

Comment: because it took less time than to get into jCarousel, which I do know nothing about and will never need, as I don't develop Javascript. Plus it's fun. Probably the OP would answer similarly. Thanks for the downvote, by the way.

Comment: @Niklas: I agree that it would be more fun to make your own.  And obviously the person asking the question agreed.  However, I feel that the average user looking for an answer to this question would be better served using jCarousel.

Comment: The average user will see both answers and decide for himself, I assume.

Answer (score 2):

No reason to reinvent the wheel.  Check out [jCarousel](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/).